# Yousign API: How to know if a procedure has been completely signed?

Tags: rest

I'm using Yousign on my onboarding process to make my users sign a contract before accessing my application.

To achieve that:

- On the YouSign UI, I manually create a new procedure from a template and copy the signature link (I get a URL like `https://staging-app.yousign.com/procedure/sign?members=/members/a8xxxxxx`)
- I copy that link on my user account
- When the user logs in, I open a modal and display the signature procedure [in an iframe](https://dev.yousign.com/#2fcbc455-2602-4163-a5fd-deee5e78546f)
- When the users has signed on the iframe, [I redirect him to a webpage](https://dev.yousign.com/#413be1c3-16a8-4085-b9b1-16ea40ecfbd5) where I trigger an event that closes the modal

At that stage, when the modal closes I'd like to check through a backend API call to YouSign API if the procedure has been fully signed.

But I can't find anything to do that in the API.

It seems I could use the GET /procedures/xxx method, but the Signature link does not contain any procedureID, only members IDs.

And there is no GET /members/xxx method, so I can't retrieve any procedure from there.

The use case of checking if a document has been signed seems pretty common for a e-signature API so I'm probably missing an obvious solution.

Comment: Hello, I have the exact same problem. How did you fixed it ?

Comment: I did not use Yousign. But they were releasing a V2 API that was supposed to fix that issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this has been improved with the release of our new API version. You can subscribe to a [webhook](https://developers.yousign.com/docs/webhooks#signature-request) to get updates about the signature (preferred approach), or [query](https://developers.yousign.com/reference/get-signature_requests-signaturerequestid) the signature directly.

Comment: Congrats for the v2 and thanks for having a look to Stack Overflow :)